# Angularjs ui router page refresh issue with nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I have defined my angular routes in angular-ui-router , I notice that when I have state like: http://localhost:9000/login loaded in my browser and when I refresh the page , I am able to view the login page if I have defined the state url as: ^/login. But if I have nested states like : http://localhost:9000/login/signup loaded in my browser and when I refresh the page, I either get a blank screen or I get a REST Get error or I am redirected to the http://localhost:9000/login page but I really want to be in the signup state which is the child state of login.

Comment: Have you enabled the html5mode which removes the "#" from the URL? If not. Try: http://localhost:9000/#/login/signup

Comment: please show some more code